# Match string value from Firebase with input value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to display data from Firestore that match the exact search query in a input field. But so far no luck...

Firebase

carname: "Ford" 
Made in: "USA"

```
<input id="input"> 

------
const input = document.querySelector('#input');

input_search.oninput = () => {
  if(input.value === doc.data().carname;) {

  database.collection('cars').where('carname', '==', input.value).get().then(
  snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {

  console.log('This car was made in: " + doc.data().Made in;


}


}
```

Comment: My quick guess is that the `input_value` should be `input.value`. If that's not it: what doesn't work about this code when you run it? Does your `oninput` get triggered at all? If not, the problem has nothing to do with Firestore yet, and you should look into how to trigger a HTML input. If the `oninput` callback does get triggered, what happens when you step through it in a debugger? Does the first `if` evaluate to `true`? I.e. does it go into that block? If so, what is `input_value`?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I changed the order, making oninput trigger the snapshot function and then ran the if-statement. It's working :)